# OxyPlot "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.dll"

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot, xamarin.wpf

I have 2 questions regarding the OxyPlot library.

1. So I'm well aware that OxyPlot is supported for Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Forms.Android, Xamarin.Forms.iOS, and Xamarin.Forms.Mac. However, I was wondering if this library supports Xamarin Forms WPF. I know it works on WPF applications, but not in Xamarin Forms WPF. I checked in NuGet Package store, and none was found.
2. I get this error regarding running my Xamarin Forms project. I am creating a Xamarin Forms WPF project that will display a chart. But I keep getting this error.
   [image: This is the error I'm getting]

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error? From my understanding, you need to initialize it. For example, for Android projects, you use

```
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();.
```

But for Xamarin Forms WPF, there is no initialization function. Can anyone help me in regards to this problem? Thank you so much.

I tried initializing, but there's no initialize function for Xamarin Forms WPF. For example:

• iOS:

```
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

• Android:

```
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

• Universal Windows:

```
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

• Windows Phone:

```
OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
```

• WPF: ???

Comment: I see no evidence that makes me think WPF is supported, and plenty to say that it is not

Comment: Yeah, I've been doing some research regarding examples and documentations. For WPF applications, it does work. But it seems I have not found any examples that show that OxyPlot supports Xamarin Forms WPF.